# apache not starting in vagrant vm

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, vagrant

I used Puphpet.com to create a Vagrant VM to be used for web development.  The problem I am having is that the VM cannot start apache on boot.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
* Starting web server apache2                                                   *
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 36 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

the system is ubuntu 12, not sure what modifications I have to make to the puppet config to fix the problem.

Comment: How are you configuring apache? Are you doing anything with authz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

author of PuPHPet here.

You're probably trying to install PHP 5.5 on an Ubuntu 12 box.

Note that I mention in two places that 5.5 is not working on Ubuntu.

To clarify:

PHP 5.5 will work on Ubuntu if you go with Nginx.

To clarify further:

It's not that PHP 5.5 is broken. Nothing is actually broken. If you install it manually it works great. The problem is that the ondrej's PPA for 5.5 installs Apache 2.4+, and the puppetlabs-apache module I am using does not work with Apache > 2.2.

If you want PHP 5.5 and want to use Apache, setup a Debian box.

Comment: Thanks!  I went with a debian box and everything is working great.

Answer (score 0):

the authz_default module is missing.
The module is not loaded, so Apache doesn't know any of the directives used by this module.

Install the module and try again.

Regarding your Puppet configuration, you have to add some lines to make it install the missing module before starting Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Debian 7.5 and PHP 5.6 after changing the option on using mod_php (I switched that on because php-fpm messed up Symfony2 dev env links). 
Then I ran `vagrant provision` and this problem started. The file `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default`. So was missing from the system.

Solved by calling `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`.